# rake aborted! PG::ConnectionBad: Error on Cloud9 when trying to run rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

as the title says, I get this error by making a simple `rake routes`.

I guess in C9, the default environment in which the commands are run is in production, because this is my Gemfile settings.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

And in my linux partition works perfect, so ... how can I make the `rake routes` run in the development test environment?

Comment: try `rake routes RAILS_ENV=development` ?

Comment: It also looks like this could be a result of the VM not having an internet connection. Sometimes this can be fixed by [restarting your workspace](https://docs.c9.io/docs/restarting-your-workspace).

Answer (score 0):

Today i was stuck on same issue. In my case for some reason my development credentials for accessing DB was deleted/removed. Now when i try to run rake routes it was giving me this error.

```
bundle exec rake routes rake routes
```

By Default it runs in development mode. So it uses credentials specified under ***development*** section in ***config/database.yml***, which in my case won't have access to database anymore.

So I changed the environment to use production credentials as

```
bundle exec rake routes rake routes RAILS_ENV=production
```

Similarly if you  want to use development then as @Van Huy Suggested in comments you can do this.

```
bundle exec rake routes rake routes RAILS_ENV=development
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also had luck running `bundle install --without production` which will make it so that pg isn't there at all in the development environment.